# Why do we use the expression of magnetic field at the centre of a current carrying coil to calculate the flux through the whole coil?

Tags: electromagnetism

While calculating the magnetic flux through a current carrying circular coil, we dot the magnetic field at the centre  with the total area of the coil. But we know that to calculate the magnetic flux, we must dot the magnetic field at a point (inside the loop) on the plane of the loop and dot it with the area element at that point, and then integrate the whole expression for the total surface. Why don't we do that in this case?

Comment: Where have you seen this incorrect method being done? This definitely is not the norm.

Comment: Search the Web first, for example :
1. [Procedure to Calculate the Inductance of a Circular Loop Near a
Metal Plate](http://www.pe.org.pl/articles/2011/9a/54.pdf), see equation (17).
2. [Self inductance of a wire loop as a curve integral](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1486.pdf), $\S$ Circular loop.

Answer (score 3):

It should be done by integration, as you describe. It's not easy to do, though. For one thing, if you approximate the wire as infinitesimally thin, you have an infinitely strong field at the edges of your integration area. So you need to take account of the wire's thickness. The mathematics is difficult, but leads to simple approximate formulae like this one (a truncation of a series).$$\Phi=\mu_0 R I \left(\ln \frac{8R}{a}-2 \right)$$ in which *R* is the circle radius and $a$ is the wire radius.

Dotting the loop area with $\vec{B}$ at the centre of the loop must surely give an answer that is too small. [Why not see for yourself, perhaps taking $R=50 $ mm and $a=0.50 $ mm ?] I'm surprised that anyone has suggested that $\Phi$ may be calculated, even approximately, by this method.

Comment: I have read it in the chapter of electromagnetic induction in my physics textbook. The topic was " Self inductance of a plane circular coil"

Comment: I have read it in the chapter of electromagnetic induction in my physics textbook. The topic was " Self inductance of a plane circular coil ". It was given as :- consider a uniform circular coil of radius r and N turns. Let I current be flowing through it, then magnetic field at its centre B = μ○ NI/2r. Thus, magnetic flux linked with the coil is NBA = N(μ○NI/2r)(pi *r²). From definition of self inductance, flux = LI. So L= μ○ *pi * N² r/2.......I am confused that why did it use the magnetic field at the centre.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the name of the textbook and its author.

Comment: This self inductance is derived in the same manner in a youtube video:- https://youtu.be/0KewvYq9XTs

Comment: Thank you. But I'd still be interested to know the name of the textbook and its author. Incidentally, did you try the calculations I suggested?

Comment: Taking the value of current as 1Ampere and values of R and a as you suggested, the flux turns out to be 2941.93 * 10^-10 wb by using  the formula that you mentioned. But calculating the flux using field at the centre gives me 492.98 *10^-10 wb. Well, the textbook in which I read it is my RBSE (state board) physics textbook for 12th class named as 'Student Advisor'. Name of the author is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. By the wrong method, I make the flux $\Phi=\frac{\pi}{2}\mu_{0} I R=9.89 \times 10^{-8}\ \text{Wb}$ but using the approximate formula I quoted, $\Phi=\left(\ln\frac{8R}{a}-2 \right)\mu_{0} I R=29.43 \times 10^{-8}\ \text{Wb}$ So the wrong method gives about a third of the approximate value. I didn't agree with your calculations; which of us is wrong?

Comment: In the wrong method, I put the value of R = 25mm as it is the radius of the loop, but in your formula, R is the diameter, so I took it as 50 mm.

Comment: My fault. Both $a$ and $R$ should be radii. I've now put this right. Sorry to have wasted your time.